Error 'Version '1.26.1*' for 'nginx' was not found' on installing Nginx version 1.26.1
I am new to Nginx and I am trying to install a specific version 1.26.1 in my server using apt-install
I use sudo apt install nginx=1.26.1* to install but I am receiving an error upon installation

Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree... Done Reading
state information... Done Package nginx is not available, but is
referred to by another package. This may mean that the package is
missing, has been obsoleted, or is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it: nginx-common
E: Version '1.26.1*' for 'nginx' was not found


I was able to install it before, but I am not able to figure out the problem here.
I am using Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS

You haven't indicated your Ubuntu version - however AFAIK the highest version of nginx in any current (up to and including 24.10) Ubuntu release is 1.26.0-2ubuntu3. So presumably you added a 3rd party repository or PPA?

@steeldriver I have installed this before. nginx -v: nginx version: nginx/1.26.1

@steeldriver is accurate: That version is not in the Ubuntu repositories yet. So perhaps you installed it from somewhere else or possibly using a different method than apt. Use which nginx and whereis nginx to determine the location installed in the filesystem; those offer important clues to the install method.
